# Merge XML files with XSLT a particular way

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to merge multiple XML files, I searched on the web an nobody do it this way so...

Let me explain;

here my first xml:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" ?>
<racine>
    <info>
        <price>50</price>
        <physic>
            <color>blue</color>
            <height>1</height>
        </physic>
    </info>
</racine>
```

The second one:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" ?>
<racine>
    <info>
        <price>100</price>
        <physic>
            <color>black</color>
            <height>2</height>
        </physic>
    </info>
</racine>
```

And i want this output;

```
<?xml version = "1.0" ?>
<racine>
    <info>
        <price>50</price>
        <physic>
            <color>blue</color>
            <height>1</height>
        </physic>
    </info>
    <info>
        <price>100</price>
        <physic>
            <color>black</color>
            <height>2</height>
        </physic>
    </info>
</racine>
```

Do you have any solutions/idea ?

Thanks and have a nice day !

Comment: "I searched on the web an nobody do it this way" - it's encouraging that people search for code they can reuse, but programming isn't just about finding a program that someone else has already written. You really shouldn't be using XSLT until you have learnt the basics, and this one really only needs the absolute basics.

Comment: @Michael Thank you for giving advice, but, I'm doing it for my work, And thanks to my boss I don't have the time to learn.

Comment: I hope your boss doesn't ask plumbers and electricians to do jobs for which they haven't been trained. If he does, I fear for your safety. (To be honest, I sometimes worry about whether it's right to give advice on this site to people who aren't qualified to do the job.)

Answer (score 1):

Considering the input XMLs shared above, they can be merged using the following XSL applied on the first input XML.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:param name="fileName" select="document('2.xml')" />
    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="racine">
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- retain existing nodes of 1.xml as is -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
            <!-- copy required nodes from 2.xml -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$fileName/racine/*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<racine>
    <info>
        <price>50</price>
        <physic>
            <color>blue</color>
            <height>1</height>
        </physic>
    </info>
    <info>
        <price>100</price>
        <physic>
            <color>black</color>
            <height>2</height>
        </physic>
    </info>
</racine>
```

Comment: Okay thanks you, but what if I have to do it with an entire folder of similar XML ?

Comment: One way is to create multiple `<xsl:param>` tags for each of the individual XML files and copy the appropriate nodes. In XSLT 1.0, the `document()` supports only 1 file at a time. If you can use XSLT 2.0, I think there is a `collection()` function that may be handy but I am not much aware of it or used it.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done almost as a one-liner:

```
<xsl:template name="main">
  <racine>
   <xsl:copy-of select="(doc('doc1.xml')|doc('doc2.xml'))/racine/*"/>
  </racine>
</xsl:template>
```